# Необходимо навести порядок в тегах по фреймворку Symfony

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, метки, синонимы-меток, удаление-метки

Существует PHP Framework Symfony. Люди, которые его используют и следят за его развитием, знают, что Symfony версий 2 и 3 друг от друга почти ничем не отличаются. Мало того, во многих моментах код обратно-совместим. Да, в Symfony 3.0 относительно 2.0 произошел серьезный рефакторинг многого, переименованы и перенесены в другие классы различные методы. До версии 3.0 обратную совместимость поддерживали для проектов от версии 2.3. В 3.0 многие проекты, разработанные на старых версиях, перестали работать, но это легко исправляется, если выполнить инструкции по апгрейду.

В этом году сообщество во главе с создателем самого фреймворка приняло решение о том, чтобы закрыть Google Groups поддержку по фреймворку и перейти полностью на StackOverflow. В [официальном блоге](http://symfony.com/blog/symfony-support-stack-overflow-as-the-main-medium) Фабьен Потенсье попросил инвертировать главный и побочный синонимы [symfony](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony) и [symfony2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony2) на английском SO. Для этого даже создали отдельную тему на [мете](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297725/need-a-moderator-to-edit-the-symfony2-tag-synonyms). Но почему-то не помогло. Сообществом [принято](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-docs/issues/4203) не плодить различные теги для Symfony2 и Symfony3, а использовать общее название Symfony, так как все же это один проект и все вопросы, заданные с тегом `symfony` относятся как к тегу [symfony2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony2), так и к тегу [symfony3](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony3). Конечно, стоит помнить, что Symfony1 - это отдельный фреймворк. И если найдется кто-то, кто до сих с ним работает, можно создать отдельный тег [symfony1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony1) или что-то типа того. Но теги [symfony2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony2) и [symfony3](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony3) нужно исключать.

Comment: кстати, специальное форматирование для меток: `[tag:symfony]` → [tag:symfony]

Comment: спасибо, поправил.

Answer (score 1):

[symfony](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony) воспринимается как метка для первой версии ПО, то есть [symfony1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony1). Если некто задает вопрос про Symfony2 или Symfony3, логично будет использовать метку с соответствующим номером. Вы же предлагаете привыкнуть, что Symfony 2&3 это [symfony](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony), а Symfony 1 это [symfony1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony1).

Думаю, проблема не в метках, а в том, что сообщество Symfony решило сделать противоестественную замену названий.  Представьте, что:

- Microsoft переименовывала бы каждую новую версию своей ос в просто Windows, а предыдущей давала бы какое-то другое имя.
- Python 3 назвали бы просто Python; тогда было бы Python 2 → [python2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python2) и Python 3 → [python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python).

Думаю, стоит позволить пользователям отмечать вопросы той меткой, по которой они потом будут их искать.

Comment: Symfony первой версии настолько специфичен, что любой человек, который будет с ним работать, будет знать, что ему соответствует только тег symfony1. А версии Symfony 2 и 3 для новичков будут сбивать с толку. Так как все англоязычное сообщество будет называть это просто Symfony, а русскоязычное будет разделять на Symfony2 и Symfony3. Я думаю, что тот факт, что на каждый вопрос придётся писать два тега, уже должен натолкнуть на мысль, что эти теги излишни.

Comment: @MichaelSivolobov: Зачем же два, просто один с нужным номером, разве этого не будет достаточно? А наименования Symfony 2 и 3 вообще исчезли из документации по фреймворку?

Comment: Вообще исчезли. Новички будут видеть версию только в информационной строке. Но все запросы в гугле идут на Symfony без указаний версий.

Comment: Разработчики grub ведь так поступили. Второй пример забыл, пока читал комментарии.