# Можно ли объединить метки angular2, angular4, angular5?

Tags: предложение, синонимы-меток, поиск

Как мы знаем, существует 2 основных разновидностей *angular*.
*AngularJS*, который основан на архитектре *MVC* и *Angular*, который основан на модели компонентов.

Суть вопроса в том, можно ли объединить метки [angular2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular2), [angular4](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular4), [angular5](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular5) под одну метку [angular](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular)? Так как мне приносит дискомфорт искать вопросы по данному фреймворку, кликая на 3 разных метки. По сути это одно и то же, которое, само по себе, различается версиями, которые, собственно, можно указать в заголовке/теле вопроса. Мы же не делаем отдельных меток по типу [java6](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java6), [java7](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java7), [nodejs6](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nodejs6), [nodejs7](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nodejs7) и т.д.

Вопрос: почему с данным фреймворком случилось так, и резонно ли их объединить?

Comment: [python-2.x], [python-3.x] :D

Comment: @andreymal ироды эти люди которые делают так )

Comment: В поиске можно использовать подстановочный знак звездочки в метках, т.е. приписка [angular*] будет искать по всем ангулярам

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight включая выше упомянутый `AngularJS` который в предпочтения альтернативной версии фреймворка не входит

Comment: То же можно сказать про HTML / HTML5, CSS / CSS3

Comment: Связанный вопрос о Symfony: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2221/181100

Comment: @D-side там более специфично так как Symfony нумеруются ка 1,2,3 где 1 отличаться  колоссально от 2,3. Тут же у нас другая ситуация так как есть `angularjs` который так и именуеться и `angular` соответственно

Comment: На данный момент angular является синонимом angularjs, поэтому вопросы по одному будут падать в метку другого. Вам придется смотреть обе метки, если вы хотите все вопросы отслеживать.

Comment: @GVArt "связанность" ни к чему не обязывает. Это я докидываю контекста о версионных метках и о том, почему они таки нужны в общем случае.

Comment: @andreymal, разве в третьем питоне не была нарушена обратная совместимость? То есть получился, по сути, новый язык со своими версионно-специфичными особенностями.

Comment: «Как мы знаем» — необязательно все это знают. Вот вы явно не знаете, чем Python 2 от Python 3 отличается, раз пишете про иродов.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, кстати, синоним лучше разбить, потому что сейчас angular2-5 официально называется `angular` (https://angular.io/) и имеет с angularjs ооочень мало общего

Comment: Не подозревая об этом обсуждении аналогичным озабтился, поэтому хочу поинтересоваться, чем дело то закончилось? Полгода уж скоро...

Comment: @Dimanoid ничем, на en so давно уже как сделали это, а тут все ждут

Answer (score 6):

Мне кажется, что стоит

- удалить синоним [angular](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular) → [angularjs](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs)
- метку [angular](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular) сделать отдельной меткой
- и добавить её ко всем вопросам с метками [angular2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular2), [angular4](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular4) и [angular5](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular5)

Причины озвучены в вопросе и комментариях:

- [angular2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular2), [angular4](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular4) и [angular5](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular5) имеют очень много общего
- соответственно большинство вопросов для Angular2/4/5 применимы и ко всем остальным версиям Angular2-5
- при этом Angular2-5 очень сильно отличается от AngularJS
- на английском Stack Overflow сделано практически так (отличается только то, что у них дополнительно [angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular2) является синонимом на [angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular)
- сейчас, если посмотреть на вопросы с меткой [angularjs](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs), то некоторые из них, как мне кажется, относятся не к AngularJS, а к Angular2-5, и произошло это из-за автоматической замены [angular](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular) → [angularjs](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs)
- в будущем, по идее, вопросов про AngularJS будет становиться всё меньше (на английском SO сейчас вопросов про AngularJS примерно в два раза меньше задаётся чем про Angular2-5), соответственно выделение [angular](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular) в отдельную метку будет всё более оправдано

Answer (score 2):

Привет всем, на http://stackoverflow.com уже замерджили `angular2`, `angular4`, `angular5` [метки](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/angular/synonyms) а у нас все еще продолжается...

[Angular, фильтрация таблицы по input[checkbox]](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/816061/angular-%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-inputcheckbox)

[Ошибка при использовании [ ( ngModel ) ]](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/815962/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-ngmodel)

[Как отследить изменения модели одним событиям в Angular 4?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/815220/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BC-%D0%B2-angular-4)

Answer (score 0):

Вот вам фильтр: [[angular2] or [angular4] or [angular5]](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular2+or+angular4+or+angular5)

Comment: Дабы не доводить это до панацеи вот вам пример использования 
 тегов `angular2`, `angular4` вместе которые не как не релевантны с определенной версией `Angular`  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/758005/angular-4-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8E-ngmodule и вопросы отмечены такими метками  это каждый 5 вопрос. Редко где встретиться вопрос именно c меткой `AngularN` который специфичен только для данной версии и нельзя будет сопоставить его с другой версии `Angular`.

Comment: Суть в том что с такими тенденциями развиться `Angular` у нас будут через года 2-3 такие теги как `Angular6`, `Angular7` и тд. Вопрос имеет ли это место быть?

Comment: Могу посоветовать использовать [angular*] чтобы получить вообще все подобные метки в поиске